# Iterator on double Linkedlist class

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator, double

This code is from a "Data Structures" book By Micheal T.Goodrigh. I'm studying on my own so I have no one to explain this code for me:

```
typedef int Elem;               // list base element type
class NodeList {              // node-based list
private:
  struct Node {               // a node of the list
    Elem elem;                // element value
    Node* prev;               // previous in list
    Node* next;               // next in list
  };
public:
  class Iterator {                // an iterator for the list
  public:
    Elem& operator*();            // reference to the element
    bool operator==(const Iterator& p) const; // compare positions
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& p) const;
    Iterator& operator++();           // move to next position
    Iterator& operator--();           // move to previous position
    friend class NodeList;            // give NodeList access
  private:
    Node* v;                  // pointer to the node
    Iterator(Node* u);            // create from node
  };
public:
  NodeList();                 // default constructor
  int size() const;               // list size
  bool empty() const;             // is the list empty?
  Iterator begin() const;         // beginning position
  Iterator end() const;           // (just beyond) last position
  void insertFront(const Elem& e);        // insert at front
  void insertBack(const Elem& e);     // insert at rear
  void insert(const Iterator& p, const Elem& e); // insert e before p
  void eraseFront();              // remove first
  void eraseBack();               // remove last
  void erase(const Iterator& p);      // remove p
private:                  // data members
  int     n;                  // number of items
  Node*   header;             // head-of-list sentinel
  Node*   trailer;                // tail-of-list sentinel
};
```

I'm very confused how I use the `insert()` method.  How do I pass an iterator to it while the iteretor is inside its class and `Node` is private?

```
int main () {
  NodeList Nl;
  N1.insert(p,5)      // How to create this p iterator and pass it to insert?
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Most of this code is similar to the STL's containers and iterators. I'd suggest you read a generic C++ tutorial, which will also cover the parts of the standard library that have their root in the STL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `begin()` method returns an `Iterator` to the front of the list.  `Iterator` is a `public` nested class of `NodeList`, so you have to quality `Iterator` when declaring a variable of that type, eg:

```
int main ()
{
    NodeList Nl;

    // optionally, insert some items into the list...

    NodeList::Iterator p = Nl.begin();
    // optionally, increment p if you want to insert in the middle of the list...

    N1.insert(p, 5);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear , really I'm very thankful for this

Answer (score 0):

To insert in the front or back of the list, you have to obtain the `begin` or `end` iterator.

To insert in the middle of the list, you have to obtain the `begin` iterator and than increment it until you reach the desired position (making sure you do not reach past the `end` iterator).

Alternatively, you can start with the `end` iterator and decrement it.

Example:

```
NodeList list;
list.insertFront(10); // put one element
list.insertFront(20); // put another element
// list is now 20 -> 10
NodeList::iterator it = list.begin();
++it;
list.insert(it, 15); // this inserts 15 before 10
// List now is 20 -> 15 -> 10
```

Comment: "*the only two insertable positions in the list are list beginning and list end*" - that is not true.  Once you have the `begin` iterator, you can advance it to the desired item before then calling `insert()`. This is how linked-list iterators always work, since a linked list does not allow for random access.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, good point, I missed the increment/decrement. Edited.

Comment: dear, 
if I make a list and call the Begin function, it's returning an  iterator object how I'll use it on may main function.
Can I use the iterator function on it ( ++ , == , .. etc ) 
I'm really don't understand why he made this operator ( ++ , == , .. etc ) while I can't use them

Comment: @SaraMohamed what makes you think you can't use them? That are all `public`. The only things that are `private` are the `Node`s themselves, and you don't need direct access to them. Simply call the `begin()` method and save the iterator to a `NodeList::Iterator` variable, then use that variable as needed.

Comment: @SaraMohamed i added some code which hopefully clears your confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate that